# MySQL Remove duplicate faster than insert IGNORE?

Tags: mysql, duplicates

Here is my table

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `download` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `date` datetime NOT NULL,
  `keyword` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `subkeyword` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `desc` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `no_file` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `url` varchar(256) NOT NULL,
  `visit` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `stat` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `keyword` (`keyword`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=161087206 ;
```

There are 161,012,173 records and 58.7 GiB table size

I created new table `tmp` with same structure but with unique keyword to avoid duplicate records than i'm using :

```
insert IGNORE into tmp select * from download;
```

It has been 2 hours but not yet finished.
Is there any fastest way?

ps.
Im using 8core xeon with 8GB ram

thank you

Comment: On what filesystem do you store MySQL's data files?

Comment: /dev/sdb1     ext3   961432072  23746696 888847376   3% /backup

Comment: Is partioning an option in the future?

Answer (score 0):

You could try to do your insert first without ignore then alter to remove duplicates:

```
ALTER IGNORE TABLE tmp ADD UNIQUE (`keyword`)
```

The `ALTER` statement will still take some time probably.

**EDIT** Oops ... left out the "TABLE" keyword. Also I'm not sure but `keyword` may be reserved so I added the backticks. Also there's apparently a bug in some versions of InnoDB that don't allow you to do this.

Also: Yes the ALTER statement can take a long time but the INSERT IGNORE statement should be doing the same thing. My answer is a suggestion of something that might be faster but it's not guaranteed.

Comment: ALTER IGNORE tmp ADD UNIQUE (keyword)

    #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'tmp ADD UNIQUE (`keyword`)' at line 1

Comment: on large tables where the physical size is larger than server memory, the ALTER statement can take a long time to run in a production environment